# UWP Windows 10 background tasks not executed

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an UWP app with some background tasks. When I execute the tasks in VS2017 while debuggin they do work and the result in the database is correct. But when I create a beta flight and install it over the store the tasks seems to be never executed.

Both Tasks have a run method who is similar to this one:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    // .. some logic
    }
    finally
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ClearPayment started");
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Then I register them in an extended Splash screen with:

```
private async void RegisterTasks()
{
    var backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    if (backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
    {
        await Mvx.Resolve<IDialogService>().ShowMessage(Strings.BackgroundAccessDeniedTitle,
                                                          Strings.BackgroundAccessDeniedByUserMessage);
    }
    else if (backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
    {
        await Mvx.Resolve<IDialogService>().ShowMessage(Strings.BackgroundAccessDeniedTitle,
        Strings.BackgroundAccessDeniedByPolicyMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        RegisterClearPaymentTask();
        RegisterRecurringPaymentTask();
    }
}

private void RegisterClearPaymentTask()
{
    // Unregister existing task first.
    if (BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Any(task => task.Value.Name == CLEAR_PAYMENTS_TASK))
    {
        BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.First(task => task.Value.Name == CLEAR_PAYMENTS_TASK).Value.Unregister(true);
    }

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
    {
        Name = CLEAR_PAYMENTS_TASK,
        TaskEntryPoint = String.Format("{0}.{1}", TASK_NAMESPACE, CLEAR_PAYMENTS_TASK)
    };

    // Task will be executed all 30 minutes
    builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));
    builder.Register();
}

private void RegisterRecurringPaymentTask()
{
    // Unregister existing task first.
    if (BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Any(task => task.Value.Name == RECURRING_PAYMENT_TASK))
    {
        BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.First(task => task.Value.Name == RECURRING_PAYMENT_TASK).Value.Unregister(true);
    }

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
    {
        Name = RECURRING_PAYMENT_TASK,
        TaskEntryPoint = String.Format("{0}.{1}", TASK_NAMESPACE, RECURRING_PAYMENT_TASK)
    };

    // Task will be executed all 30 minutes
    builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));
    builder.Register();
}
```

Currently I unregister every task on startup and register them again. I read somewhere that this is the recommended proceedure to ensure in case of an adjustemnt on the tasks the new logic is executed.

In the appmanifest I have registered the background tasks with
[image]

And

[image]

There is no exception here, so I assume that the entry points are correct.
What could be the reason the they are not working properly or how can I further investigate?

URL GitHub repository: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox

Comment: What's the result if you deploy the app to local machine? Not debug it in the Visual Studio.

Comment: If I just deploy it as debug to my local pc and do not trigger, then nothing happens.

Comment: is the github repolink the solution where this issue is occurring?

Comment: To the whole project, yes.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT just noticed that the background job is working when I deploy it locally. As it seems just not that fast as I would expect.

Comment: I'm not sure what "not that fast" mean here, but for a time span trigger, for example, if you set 15 minute, the background task will be triggered in about 15-30 minutes, not 15 minutes grantee.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Im aware of that. I just noticed that I set it to 30 minutes and after a couple of hours nothing changed. But a couple of days later it seemed like it did finally. But it still seems to have an issue somewhere.